# How to change link color using Rmdformats with readthedown theme?

Tags: css, r-markdown

I use Rmdformats with the Readthedown theme to generate a HTML file. I would like to change the link color (switching from red to blue). For that, I've seen i need to use a CSS file that overwrites default parameters. I did try many things but it does not work (however other changes in the CSS like the title color work).

Here is a MVE of the RMD file:

```
---
output: rmdformats::"readthedown"
css: myCSS.css
---

Done with [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) and [Rmdformats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmdformats/versions/1.0.2)
```

Based on another post in a forum, here is the myCSS.css file (I only reported changes with respect to links)

```
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:link,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:visited,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
background-color: #0000FF
}
```

Link color does not change.

I also did try

```
a:hover{
color: #0000FF
}

a:link{
color: #0000FF
}

a:visited{
color: #0000FF
}

a:focus{
color: #0000FF
}
```

However, it does not change color either. :(

Could someone help me?

Many thanks !

Eric

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention I use the readthedown theme of rmdformats

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you try

```
a {
color: #0000FF
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your suggestion Noel. I tried but it does not work either. I also tried  #main a
{color: #000000;background-color: #0000FF} in case the a attribute should be specified to some "context" (like main)

Answer (score 0):

I added "#main" before every intructions and it seems to work (except for the "mouse over" attribute that is not overwritten,... I do not know why...)

Here is the code in case some encounters the same issue.

```
#main a:link {
  color: #5A7B9C;
}

/* visited link */
#main a:visited {
  color: #095484;
}

/* mouse over link */
#main a:hover {
  color: #8ebf42;
}

/* selected link */
#main a:active {
  color: #716464;
}
```